# What is the shortest path equation between 2 points on the surface of $z = xy$?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Given two points on the surface $z=xy$, $A=(x_0,y_0)$, $B=(x_1,y_1)$. How to present the shortest path between $A$ and $B$? I haven't learn about differential geometry, but I know about Calculus and Linear Algebra. Looking forward for help!
[image]

Comment: @WillJagy Hi, what I want to get is the geodesic curve between two given points. However, the y=x, y=-x, x axes and y axes may not go pass through points A and B.

Comment: Or we can think as the shortest path between A and B on the z = xy surface.

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25620/geodesics-on-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid/

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks very much! Your link helps a lot!